# Zend Framework: Add form in layout

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I create login form andd add in UserController->loginAction:

```
 public function loginAction() {
    $form = new Application_Form_Login();

    $this->view->loginForm = $form;
}
```

How to add my form in layouts/scripts/header.phtml, because I try this, but not work:

```
<?php echo $this->loginForm ?>
```

If I echo form in views/scripts/user/login.phtml I see login form.

That is my login form:

```
class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form {

public function init() {
    $this->setDecorators(array('FormElements', 'Form'))
            ->setAction("/user/login/");

    $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text(array('name' => 'username', 'class' => 'input-text'));
    $username->setRequired(true)
            ->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper',));

    $this->addElements(array($username));
}

}
```

Comment: What ended up working?  You can put your solution as an answer and then accept it and others can upvote it too.

Answer (score 1):

Since a layout is separate from your view object, you need to assign the form to the layout.

In your controller:

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $form = new Application_Form_Login();

    // assign the form to the layout
    $this->_helper->layout()->loginForm = $form;
}
```

In your layout:

```
<?php if ($this->layout()->loginForm): ?>
    <?php echo $this->layout()->loginForm; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Try this instead:

```
// in controller:
$form = new Application_Form_Login();
$this->view->placeholder('loginForm')->set($form);

---------------

// in layout script:
$form = $this->placeholder('loginForm');
if ($form instanceof Zend_Form) {
    echo $form;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I try this and nothing I don't see form

Comment: Layout is just a placeholder so if you assign something to it from your controller or view it should be available in the layout itself.  The above code works fine for me on ZF 1.11.11 and 1.11.12

Comment: What is your code now?  Are you sure a valid form object is being assigned to the layout?  Are you trying to render the form in a view or layout now?  The value in the layout will only be set when you access the `UserController::loginAction` since that is where it gets assigned from.

Comment: I guess that `var_dump($this->layout()->loginForm);` in your layout returns `NULL`?  Is that correct?

Comment: Is `header.phtml` your layout or is your actual layout rendering `header.phtml`?  If so how is it being rendered?

Comment: I render header.phtml in layout.phtml, and I try with var_dump result is NULL

Comment: Ok it made no difference for me if I rendered a view script like that in my layout and had `<?php echo $this->layout()->loginForm; ?>` in `header.phtml` which is rendered from `layout.phtml`.

Comment: I need to render tihs $this->layout()->loginForm or?

Comment: You should just have to echo it in `header.phtml`.  `<?php echo $this->layout()->loginForm ?>`

Comment: Yes, <?php echo $this->layout()->loginForm ?> is in header.phtml not in layout.phtml

Comment: Are you using `Zend_Application` and are you sure that `$this->_helper->layout()->loginForm = $form;` is being executed and that `$form` is a valid form object?

Comment: Why I need to use Zend_Application, I think form need Zend_Form, I add my login form in my first post

Comment: When you use `Zend_Application` and `Zend_Layout` it sets up those placeholders.

Comment: Where I need to add Zend_Application and Zend_Laout, to work layouts I add $this->bootstrap('layout');
        $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
        $view = $layout->getView(); in Bootstrap.php

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't working, see my edit and see if that works for you

Comment: Not work, var_dump write: object(Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Container)#115 (0) { }

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the render function:

```
<?php
    echo $this->loginForm->render();
?>
```

Comment: The `__toString()` method renders the form so its fine to just echo it as is being done in the question.  No need to call render directly.